# Formly Form loading hanging site performance

Tags: angular-formly

I have implemented complex custom wrapper.
If the FORM contain 10+ custom wrapper it is hanging HTML UI page for some seconds.

For example when ng-if is true, 5+ seconds HTML hanged.

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="showForm && fields && model">
    <formly-form [model]="model" [fields]="fields" [options]="options" [form]="form"
      (modelChange)="onModelChange($event)"></formly-form>
  </form>
```

Is there any Event when the FORM loading is completed?
Can we run it in web worker?

Comment: I think you should check the length of the "fields"-array in your if statement, like `...&& fields.length`, instead of only the existance of the array itself.

Comment: Whatever is the conditions, if I add the length also, After that this formly-form tag will load in browser. On the loading time it will hang. Basically formly taking some time to generate the full dynamic FORM for us. If a add loader also, Since that loader is a UI element it is not working since UI hanged.